# Nodejs crypto - Store IV

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs, password-encryption

I'd like to store encrypted passwords on Firebase. When the user types in their password, I want the code to pull the encrypted password on Firebase, decrypt it, and compare if it matches the user-entered password. The password isn't login-related so I can't use social login services

I have the secret key stored in .env but I'm struggling with what to do with the IV. If I store it as a String and then convert it back to Buffer, I get an invalid IV error. If I store just the encrypted text, I need the same IV to be able to decrypt it.

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const crypto = require('crypto')
require('dotenv').config();

let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)

const encrypt = text => {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-ctr', process.env.SECRET_KEY, iv)
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf-8', 'hex')
    encrypted += cipher.final('hex')

    return encrypted
}

const decrypt = encrypted => {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', process.env.SECRET_KEY, iv)
    let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'hex', 'utf-8')
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8')

    return decrypted
}

const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    const encrypted = encrypt('unlockedtext')
    const decrypted = decrypt(encrypted)
    console.log(decrypted);

    console.log("server started on " + PORT)
});
```

Comment: `I want the code to pull the encrypted password on Firebase`  this is a very bad idea. To validate the user passwords, please use `slow salted hash`. Please see https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm   Or maybe better - delegate the authentication to reliable parties, who know what they are doing (AWS Cognito, Okta, Auth0, IBM AppId,... whatever)

Comment: As for encryption, IV needs to be stored along the ciphertext, usually prepended to the encrypted data. But please don't store passwords, even encrypted.

Comment: @gusto2 if i don't store passwords, what can i do to save it

Comment: You can store a hash of the password. When authenticating, then compare the stored hash with a hash of the user-entered input. You wrote that the password is not login-related, maybe describing the use-case could help to understand the requirements

Answer (score 0):

iv is in encrypted text. it is before ':'.

You can get it by:

```
let textParts = encryptedText.split(':');
let iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift(), 'hex');
```